# How do I export Excel 2016 data into another spreadsheet using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, export, reporting

I am attempting to send multiple users an Excel spreadsheet containing a form that collects data. I would like to append their input data to the bottom row of common file. Is there a way for each of these users to be able to "submit" their input data, which I've collected in the form of a table, and export to a separate spreadsheet?

Comment: If you already have an Access database AND ultimately want the data back in Access, I'd suggest building the form in a front-end Access database with links to your backend database. Each user would use the front-end for data entry. No need for purchasing additional MS-Access licenses - they would install the free runtime version from Microsoft.

Comment: @dbmitch just saved you weeks of development and maintenance time :-).

Comment: Thanks @dbmitch. I don't have an Access database built already. All of the calculations necessary for the form are in a hidden tab in the Excel sheet. I was using the workbook for some modeling, and now we need to collect data on a short time frame. In hindsight, it would've been better to build the database in Excel. That said, is there any way to create a macro that would append data to the bottom of a table on another Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: I would add your last line in your last comment to your question. And maybe even in your title. The two solutions have very different answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following objects to send your collection spreadsheet to multiple users.

```
' Outlook variables
Dim oOlAp As Object, oOlns As Outlook.Namespace, oOlInb As Object, oOlInb1 As Object
Dim oOlItm As Object, oOlAtch As Object

' Get Outlook instance
Set oOlAp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
Set oOlns = oOlAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

In that spreadsheet, use the same objects to send the answer table back to you.

Then in a "upload" spreadsheet that runs on your computer, use those same objects to extract all said tables from the answer emails.

After that you can use the normal excel interface to populate your access database.

Comment: There's a lot of missing pieces in this suggestion. It's a lot more code and coordination than you're suggesting.

Comment: Well, I have already made a sheet that will, 1 look in an outlook folder for xls files, extract them, import the data worksheet then integrate with the data into the database table.  Writing to access probably isn't very different than writing to any other normal worksheet.  In my case the hardest part was figuring out the outlook interface so the user wouldn't have to handle files at all.

Comment: Excellent - if you can share more than the above very basic start code,  it would be a much more useful answer. Since the OP doesn't even have an Access database, I'm sure your solution would be a welcome alternative

Comment: There are so many components to this, the question should really be broken down into component parts. I can't post my file because it's full of confidential data. Also it is dozens of page of code.

The logic is something like this
look for mail in "input" folder (you need to create an outlook filter to put these files apart, I guess it's possible to read every mail and search for an attachement of the correct file name)
unpack the file (in my case they were zipped with a password in the body of the text)

Comment: load the file in excel
find the row containing header description
identify which column is which information (in my case that could change, sometimes the columns would move so I had to use instr(1,mycolumn,constColumnTag) to tell which column was which
now copy each row of the input worksheet into the output worksheet.
(then I had to eliminate duplicates, or rather not copy duplicate entries)

He would also need to make another excel 
When you open it, it asks users for every piece of information you need.

Comment: There are so many ways to do this, it could be a series in inputbox commands, a userform or just record that from the Sheet1 worksheet.
And you need a send button, that will use the objects I posted earlier to use outlook to save and post the excel file back to the file collector mailbox